# Uitable editing mode make my cell button displays outside the cell

Tags: iphone

i am using UItable view to show data. i have UIbutton in each cell on right side.when i select edit mode in table my UIButton displays outside from table.please tell me what should i do.

krishan

Comment: when you enable edit mode for UItableView then cell size is decrease from 320 because red button appear on left hand side. you use custom cell or through coding add UIButton to cell contenview.

Answer (score 0):

Use either autoresizingMask in code or the Size Inspector in IB to change the behavior to what you want, depending on how you created your button (code or IB).  You can tell it to keep the left margin at a constant size, or change the width, or whatever you decide looks best.

Comment: thanks philip.i found one solution for this add Uibutton in accessoryview of table so when i select edit mode the button hide.